# How to place title at the centre of header tag just using css?

Tags: html, css

So basically, I have this piece of code which was supposed to help place my site's title at the center of the website header, however - my code is not doing what it's supposed to do as it was told to, and I can't locate where I went wrong.

The text box is what gets me, it's supposed to place the title text at the center of the header but it doesn't; it's at the top left corner of the screen overlaying the logo that I and which is also placed in the header section.

```css
.header {
  height: 95vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(126, 213, 111, 0.8), rgba(39, 179, 133, 0.8)), url(../img/image01.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  position: relative;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75vh, 0 100%);
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.heading-primary {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.heading-primary-main {
  display: block;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 35px;
}

.heading-primary-sub {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 17.4px;
}
```

I have tried using transform - translate and the top and left properties but keeping the current values keeps the text at the top left corner of the screen. If I change the values to all positive numbers it goes to the centre but is not responsive.

Comment: Can you add html code too ?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you can provide your html too. From what I can see in your css, text-box should be at the center of your header if you put it inside a div which have a class header.

```
<div class="header">
<span class="text-box">My Title</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make child element `.text-box` centered just set `text-align` property of parent to `center` and make sure `display`  attribute is `block`  and I think that alone should do the trick. I'll assume `.header` is the direct parent of `text-box`

```
 .text-box{
   ...nothing specifically needed here
  }
 .header{
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  ....
```